# Percent split with where condition in SAS

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and data analytics in general. So sorry if my question sound too dumb. 
I have a dataset of brand medicine with three variables. Variable 1 contains the drug name, variable two contains whether that drug is BRANDED, Generic or Brand-Generic and variable 3 contains the total sale of that drug. 
What I want is percent split the BRANDED, GENERIC AND BRANDED GENERIC drugs among total drug sale. The final output should look like 
Branded : 35%
Generic : 25%
Branded-Generic : 40%

Any help with a sas code which would do that is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: you can use proc freq. check this link  and try with your date. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect025.htm

Answer (score 0):

So you want a % sale split! You can try using SQL (`proc sql`) to get your desired answer.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select drug_type, sum(total_sale) as tot_sale
from have
group by drug_type;

create table want as 
select *, tot_sale/sum(tot_sale) as percent_sale format=percent10.2
from want;
quit;
```

I created a table 'want' that will have total sale for each drug type. Using that table, I created a column that has the calculated sale percentage and formatted it to a percent (for easy view).

Of course, there are other ways of doing it, like using `proc summary` or `proc freq` or even a `data step`. But as a beginner, I guess starting out with SQL would be a good decision.